# Incorrect Profit/Loss Calculation in Tradingview Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I am trying to calculate my profit/loss for a trading strategy using Tradingview Pinescript. My capital is 10,00,000 and I want to risk 10% (1,00,000). My entry price is 35,606.10 and exit price is 35,500, resulting in a loss of 106.1 per share. I am trading 909 shares, which results in a loss of 96,444.9 (~1,00,000). However, Tradingview is showing a loss of 24,11,122.50. I do not have any commission added to my trade.

I am not sure why the profit/loss calculation is incorrect. Can someone please help me identify what I am doing wrong in my calculation or if there is an issue? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the symbol and it's syminfo.pointvalue of the symbol? do you use currency conversion? Second screenshot is the wrong one, bc it set to 1 contracts, but you're using percents of equity.

Comment: symbol BANKNIFTY, pointvalue is 25
no curency conversion.

Screenshot is correct as I'm calculating the quantity in the code

`equity_risk=strategy.equity * input_quantity / 100
long_quantity := equity_risk / (high - long_sl)
short_quantity := equity_risk / (short_sl - low)`

Comment: ok and now you can multiply long_quantity * 25 and get your result

Comment: (35500−35606.10)  * 909 * 25 = −2411122.5

Comment: point value means that 1 contract costs *X more